# Beamer: Remove the thin line between the header and the frametitle

Tags: beamer, templates, headline

I'm trying to modify the `AnnArbor` template. For this I would like to get rid of the small line between the header and the frame title (see image).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%Theme
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

% Theme colors
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg=blue}


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame title}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which creates this slide. You can see the thin line where the red arrow is pointing to.

[image]

I am not sure if the line comes from the beamer or if it's a problem with the PDF viewer, but I would be glad for a simple way to remove it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, so I'd guess it's a problem of your PDF viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a viewer issue. The only viewer with which I can reproduce the problem is mac preview. It looks fine in adobe reader and the poppler based viewer of texstudio.

Anyway, you can avoid the problem by adding a bit of negative space before the frametitle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%Theme
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

% Theme colors
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg=blue}


\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-0.05cm}{}


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame title}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```